# Python logger adding additional characters in the log file

Tags: python

I am trying to use the python logger module for directing the logs to the console and also to the file. but I see that there are some special characters added in the log file, that I dont see on the console.

```
^[[0m
2018-02-23 03:20:10:INFO ::logger_test.py -<module>(..) Line:21::^[[32m
```

I dont understand from where the `"[["` are getting added in the prefix `"^[[0m"` and suffix of  `"[[32m".`

My configuration is as follows:

```
[formatter_console_info_formatter]
format=%(message)s


[formatter_console_error_formatter]
format=%(levelname)s ::%(filename)s -%(funcName)s(..) Line:%(lineno)d::%(message)s

[formatter_file_formatter]
format=%(asctime)s:%(levelname)s ::%(filename)s -%(funcName)s(..) Line:%(lineno)d::%(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

my suspicion is the `%(message)s`.

Any idea how I can avoid the `"[["` ?

Comment: Tried to edit with code tags to help, but lost in the log output. Consider bracketing your log statements with ticks (i.e. ``)

Comment: That looks like [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for colours. Can you please show what messages you're sending to the logger? If you tried to colour your output, that won't work in a file.

Comment: @ Norrius.  It was indeed the coloring configuration that is messing up the logs. Appreciate your help.